# Overriding Delay and Loop

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Is it possible to override the delay to end the loop?
What I wanted to happen is to end the loop by button press. But it seemed to finish the loop before executing the `next()` method.

```cpp
void blink1() {
  loop_flag = true;
  while (loop_flag) {
    // Loop for Lights
    for (int x = 0; x < LED_IN; x++) {
      btn_press = digitalRead(btn_1);
      if (!btn_press) {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        next(); //loop_flag = false; is stored
      } else {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(led[x], HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(led[x], LOW);
      }
    }
  }
}

void next() {

  Serial.write("pressed next \n");
  flag = getFlag(flag); // Sets new Flag
  loop_flag = false; //ends the loop flag
  delay(100); //delay for button friendly

}
```

Comment: Maybe add a check for `loop_flag` being `false` in the `for` loop too? Like e.g. `x < LED_IN && loop_flag`?

Comment: Why do you not remove the delay then? It seems entirely superfluous. The loop will end, and the function will return after `loop_flag` was set.

Comment: Then it will not blink. Delay is used to set the time of how long the LED will stay on.

Comment: This is strangely structured for Arduino code, there should be a `loop()` function which is where the logic should happen. Who calls `blink1()`?

Comment: `blink1()` is called in the `loop()`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s going to finish the for loop even if you press the button. Once it finishes the call to  next(), it returns right back into that for loop. Add break; after your call to next()